# How to write a function that return a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I would like to know whether a function could return a loop?

My code is as follow:

```
def looping():
    a = [25,50,75,100, 200, 300]
    for x in a:
        return x
print(looping())
```

When I print it it returned:

Output:

```
[25]
```

Expected output:

```
25
50
75
100
200
300
```

Is this possible?

Comment: instead of `return x` you can just `print(x)`

Comment: `yield` instead of `return` (and `list(looping())`)

Comment: I am hoping to return each of the element for writing it into file name so i cant print it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the problem with your existing code is that once you `return`, the function is over. So, you just return the first value and you're done.

---

A function can't return a loop, because a loop isn't a kind of value.

A function can return an *iterable*, which is a value that can be looped over. There are a few ways to do this:

---

You could use `yield`, as in most of the other answers, to make your function a generator function, so it returns an iterator over all of the things you `yield`.

But `yield`ing inside a loop is just a clumsy way of doing `yield from`, so really, you should just do that:

```
def looping():
    a = [25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300]
    yield from a
for x in looping():
    print(x)
```

---

You can instead return an iterator directly:

```
def looping():
    a = [25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300]
    return iter(a)
for x in looping():
    print(x)
```

---

Or, most simply of all: a sequence, like a list, is just as iterable as an iterator. So, if you have a list, just return it:

```
def looping():
    a = [25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300]
    return a
for x in looping():
    print(x)
```

---

While we're at it, you don't even really need an explicit loop there. You can call a function that hides the loop inside, like `join`:

```
print('\n'.join(looping()))
```

Or you can even splat the iterable directly to `print`:

```
print(*looping(), sep='\n')
```

Although in this case, I think the loop is perfectly reasonable, so if you're happy with it, stick with it.

Comment: Hi sir, is there a way to use the function like this? with open("text_{}.txt".format(looping()),"w+") as outfile: outfile.write(something)...... I wanted it to automatically renamed according to my input within the list. Sometimes I have too many files and wanted to name it according to the number

Comment: @JJson No, but you could just do `for name in looping():` `with open("text_{}.txt".format(name), "w+") as outfile:`.

Comment: @JJson I think what you’re looking for is array-oriented computation, like in APL or J. Python does provide _some_ support for that, through third-party libraries like NumPy, but it’s mainly designed around a different paradigm, iterators: instead of hiding loops, it makes loops as powerful and ubiquitous as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you merely want to output the contents of a list, you may use the `.join()` feature.

`print("\n".join([str(x) for x in a]))`

If you want to utilize loops, use a generator, and write the loop outside as shown.

```
def looping():
    a = [25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300]
    for x in a:
        yield x

for x in looping():
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without a loop using just `join` and `map` :

```
>>> print('\n'.join(map(str,a)))
```

---

But, if it is a loop that you are looking for, then using `return` is the wrong way to go about it, as `return` would give back the control from the function in its first encounter itself.

Instead, use `yield` or `yield from` :

> yield from iterable is essentially just a shortened form of 
>   `for item in iterable: yield item`

```
>>> def looping(): 
        a = [25,50,75,100, 200, 300] 
        yield from a

>>> for ele in looping(): 
        print(ele)
```

#driver values :

```
IN : a = [25,50,75,100, 200, 300]
OUT: 25
     50
     75
     100
     200
     300
```